# taking a picture while recording a video

Tags: android, camera, commonsware-cwac

I'm building my own camera application and I'm looking for a way to take a picture while recording a video. (android 15+)

Is this possible in CWAC-camera or should I cut a frame out of the video.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible in CWAC-camera

Not that I am aware of.

> should I cut a frame out of the video

It is possible that a `PreviewCallback` is invoked while `MediaRecorder` is recording. I have not experimented with that. If it is, my guess is that will give you better results than will grabbing a frame.

Comment: I have been testing but I can't get a callback. I tried to implement `Camera.PreviewCallback` in fragments, activities, host but it never gets called. Were should I implement: `public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)`